# How to disable interactions on a FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` backed by a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and at a certain point I want to display a *popup* over that `ViewPager`, hence disabling all the interactions on it.

Usually, when using a `ListView`or a `GridView`this is done by overriding the [`areAllItemsEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29) method of the backing adapter, however such method doesn't exist for the [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) (or its [parent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) since it doesn't extend the [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!